# ColdFusion - how to edit a record?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I want to edit the Record2 but when I click the Edit button it always display the info of Record1.  If I click any other Edit buttons it only display the info of Record1. How does it know which record I want to edit? Please help. Thank you.

```
<cfform name="formName" action="edit.cfm" method="post">
....some additional codes.....
<cfloop query="qryName">
Record1_data     Edit button
Record2_data     Edit button
Record3_data     Edit button
Record4_data     Edit button
</cfloop>
....some additional codes.....
</cfform>
```

Comment: Showing "Edit button" as pseudocode does not help us answer your question, since that is probably where your error is.  Please show the real code.  Also, please show the code for edit.cfm.

Comment: My guess would be that whatever value you are passing to your for to tell it what record to display is passing the same value for every button, but without some real code, there is no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a really good reason I'd really shy away from using `cfform` there's rarely a good reason to use it

You need to pass in some sort of form variable that has the corresponding `ID` to what you're pulling into the database.

```
<form name="formName" action="edit.cfm" method="post">
  <cfloop query="qryName">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Record" value="#qryName.ID#" /> Record #qryName.ID#
  </cfloop>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't share your opinion of cfform.  Like most things in ColdFusion, it's one of those things that makes life easy.

Comment: Dan - no, it doesn't. It makes things harder..especially when you want/need to do thing the 'real' way. Cfform and all the other UI tags are merely crutches CF developers use instead of actually learning JavaScript.